# Duda con mensaje de confirmación en CRUD

Tags: jquery, express, bootstrap-4, modal, pug

Mi app está desarrollada en Express.js y resumiendo un poco lo que hace es un proyecto que te da mozilla developer un tutorial CRUD pero ahora empece a desarrollar lo que es el front-end por mi cuenta y tengo una duda acerca que en mi plantilla pug quisiera que al momento de eliminar un libro me saliera un mensaje de confirmacion como libro borrado y en caso de que no se puede eliminar porque contiene una instancia de libro me diga "no se puede eliminar porque contiene una instancia de libro" dicha lógica esta desarrollada en una plantilla pug pero es una pagina aparte quisiera desarrollarlo dentro de un modal al momento me sirve y elimina el libro con el código que tengo pero no puedo lograr que aparezca la leyenda de "libro borrado" o "no se puede eliminar porque contiene una instancia de libro" estoy leyendo que con llamada ajax jquery pero no se por donde empezar.

mi controlador:

```
exports.book_delete_get = function (req, res, next) {

    async.parallel({
        book: function (callback) {
            Book.findById(req.params.id)
                .populate('author')
                .populate('genre')
                .exec(callback);
        },
        book_instance: function (callback) {
            BookInstance.find({ 'book': req.params.id }).exec(callback)
        },
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (results.book == null) { // No results.
            res.redirect('/catalog/books');
        }
        // Successful, so render.
        res.render('book_delete', { title: 'Delete Book', book: results.book, book_instance: results.book_instance });
    });

};

exports.book_delete_post = function (req, res, next) {

    async.parallel({
        book: function (callback) {
            Book.findById(req.body.id)
                .populate('author')
                .populate('genre')
                .exec(callback);
        },
        book_instance: function (callback) {
            BookInstance.find({ 'book': req.body.id }).exec(callback)
        },
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        // Success
        if (results.book_instance.length > 0) {
            // Book has bookinstances. Render in same way as for GET route.
            res.render('book_delete', { title: 'Delete Book', book: results.book, book_instance: results.book_instance });
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Book has no bookinstances. Delete object and redirect to the list of bookinstace.
            Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id, function deleteBook(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                // Success - go to book list
                res.redirect('/catalog/books');
            })
        }
    });
};
```

y mi plantilla nueva pug donde quiero mostrar un mensaje de confirmacion, success y no se puede borrar

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Lista de Libros
  p
    a(href='/catalog/book/create' class="btn btn-success mt-4") Nuevo Libro

  div(class="container")
    table(class="table mt-5 mb-5")
      thead
        tr
          th Libros
          th Autor
          th Acciones

        - book_list.sort(function(a, b) {let textA = a.title.toUpperCase(); let textB = b.title.toUpperCase(); return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;});
        each book in book_list
         tr(class="table-hover")
            td #{book.title}
            td #{book.author.name}
            td 
              a(href=book.url+'/update')
                i(class="fas fa-pencil-alt pr-2")
              i(class="fas fa-trash-alt pr-2" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=("#myModal-" + book._id))
                .modal.fade(id=("myModal-" + book._id) tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=("myModalLabel" + book._id) aria-hidden="true")
                  .modal-dialog
                    .modal-content
                      .modal-header
                        h4.modal-title(id=("myModalLabel" + book._id)) #{book.title}
                      .modal-footer
                        p.p-success(class="mb-3") Estas seguro que deseas eliminar este libro?
                        form.form-delete(method='POST' action=book.url+'/delete')
                          div.form-group
                            input#id.form-control(type='hidden',name='id', required='true', value=book._id )
                          button.btn.btn-danger(type='submit') Eliminar
                          button.btn.btn-primary(type="button",data-dismiss="modal", class="ml-2") Cancelar


              a(href=book.url)
                i(class="fas fa-info pr-2")
        else
          li There are no books.
```

la plantilla que realice en el tutorial y original es esta:

```
extends layout

block content

  h1(class="mb-4") Eliminar Libro
  h3 #{book.title}

  p #[strong Autor:] 
    a(href=book.author.url) #{book.author.name}
  p #[strong Síntesis:] #{book.summary}
  p #[strong Código:] #{book.isbn}
  p #[strong Genero:] 
    each val in book.genre
      a(href=val.url) #{val.name}


  hr

  if book_instance.length

    p #[strong Borrar todas las copias antes de eliminar el libro.]

    div(style='margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px')

      h4 Copias

      each book_copy in book_instance
        hr
        if book_copy.status=='Disponible'
          p.text-success #{book_copy.status}
        else if book_copy.status=='Mantenimiento'
          p.text-danger #{book_copy.status}
        else
          p.text-warning #{book_copy.status} 
        p #[strong Síntesis:] #{book_copy.imprint}
        if book_copy.status!='Disponible'
          p #[strong Disponible para:] #{book_copy.due_back_formatted}
        p #[strong Id:] 
          a(href=book_copy.url) #{book_copy._id}

  else
    p Estas seguro que quieres eliminar este libro?

    form(method='POST' action='')
      div.form-group
        input#id.form-control(type='hidden',name='id', required='true', value=book._id )

      button.btn.btn-danger(type='submit') Eliminar

  div(class="icon-return")
    a(href='/catalog/books' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Regresar")
      i(class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left mb-5 mt-5" style="font-size:35px;color: #339af0")
```

pero yo quisiera no usar esa plantilla y usar solo la nueva con un modal y que me diga ya sea si tengo instancias o no y me deje eliminar y mas que nada saber por donde guiarme o leer para resolver esto muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Imagino que por el entusiasmo de escribir tu primera pregunta en el sitio, has olvidado por completo usar signos de puntuación para separar las ideas en tu pregunta. No somos inquisidores de la lengua, pero es más fácil entender tu explicación si la misma tiene una redacción más cuidada. Saludos